# Create config file for each module Yii ver 1

Tags: php, yii

Same as the title, i want to create config file for each module in yii, example:

```
test/
   TestModule.php             the module class file
   components/                containing reusable user components
   config/                    containing config class files
      main.php                the config file  <===
   views/                     containing view files for widgets
   controllers/               containing controller class files
      DefaultController.php   the default controller class file
   models/                    containing model class files
   views/                     containing controller view and layout files
      layouts/                containing layout view files
      default/                containing view files for DefaultController
         index.php
```

What is the solution? Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your main config and point to config file for each module:

```
return array(
    ......
    modules => array (
          require('path./to/configfile1.php');  //first module config
          require('path/to/configfile2.php');   //second module config
    ),
    .......
)
```

and in your module config file

```
return array(
    'class' => 'alias.to.class',
    'param1' => 'val1'
    .......

)
```